# Material design: naviagtion drawer with tabs and recyclerview

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I have a problem with the navigation drawer. I want to know how to display recyclerview when the user clicks on different element of each menu.
Here are some source code and an illustrative capture

[image]

N.B: different menu items ("Accueil, Contacts Staff, etc ...") are in an .xml file in the layout.

MainActiviy.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    setupWindowAnimations();

    //définir la toolbr en tant qu'actionbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, 0, 0);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });

    //on remplit notre viewpager, comme à notre habitude
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Tab " + position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }
    });

    //indique au tablayout quel est le viewpager à écouter
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupWindowAnimations() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        Explode explode = new Explode();
        getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);

        Fade fade = new Fade();
        getWindow().setReenterTransition(fade);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




@OnClick(R.id.fab)
public void onFabClick() {
    Snackbar.make(fab, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            }).show();
 }
}
```

Comment: On every menuItem you can get ItemId and load data relevant with it and set it to recycleview adapter

Comment: I don't understant. Please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Sample source code for you

```
  public class NavActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Please put an example in // handle the action for me -- I want to have more comprehension. 
Thanks

Comment: This is the most basic thing. If you don't understand that, you need to start reading for yourself on easier tutorials and the documentation on the official Android website. There's no point in copy-pasting if you don't understand the code. Read through the NavigationView documentation, read 1 or 2 tutorials on it, and you will get it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html People already gave you great answers, they can't make your app for you.

Comment: Same goes for the recycler view although it's a bit harder to use. Look for Codepath tutorials. I find them really good. RecyclerView - https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and come you back.

Answer (score 0):

Not understand exactly what you want. Where do you want to display recycler view? You already have OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, just check which menu you have clicked and do what you want:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.contact:
          // do anything you want, ex
          showContactList();
          break;

}
```

the function to show your contact list

```
private void showContactList(){
    List<Contact> data = getYourDataSomeHow();
    yourAdapter.setData(data);
    yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I want to display some contact information and the possibilty to call in each recyclerview. you see ? Where exactly have I to put 

"...boolean onNavigationItemSelected..." 

in my MainActivity and please write an example of recyclerview I have to put

Comment: So, you mean that, when click on menu contact, you want to show some contact item on your recyclerview, right?

Comment: Check my updated answer, depend on your layout the solution maybe diff, but that is the general way. In your code, you are using tablayout then i guess that your recyclerview was putted in your RecyclerViewFragment.